# I got npm error while installing any npm or plugin in ionic 3 project

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, ionic3

I'm Developing Hybrid Application using ionic-3. I'm getting npm error when i install any plugin or npm (like "npm install --save @ionic-native/paypal").
Everything working well until i install npm.

> Error

```
npm ERR! path F:\ionic_2\Ecommerce\material\node_modules\ionic-angular
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'F:\ionic_2\Ecommerce\material\node_modules\ionic-angular' -> 'F:\ionic_2\Ecommerce\material\node_modules\.ionic-angular.DELETE'
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'F:\ionic_2\Ecommerce\material\node_modules\ionic-angular' -> 'F:\ionic_2\Ecommerce\material\node_modules\.ionic-angular.DELETE'
npm ERR!   cause:
npm ERR!    { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'F:\ionic_2\Ecommerce\material\node_modules\ionic-angular' -> 'F:\ionic_2\Ecommerce\material\node_modules\.ionic-angular.DELETE'
npm ERR!      errno: -4048,
npm ERR!      code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!      path: 'F:\\ionic_2\\Ecommerce\\material\\node_modules\\ionic-angular',
npm ERR!      dest: 'F:\\ionic_2\\Ecommerce\\material\\node_modules\\.ionic-angular.DELETE' },
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename \'F:\\ionic_2\\Ecommerce\\material\\node_modules\\ionic-angular\' -> \'F:\\ionic_2\\Ecommerce\\material\\node_modules\\.ionic-angular.DELETE\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!   path: 'F:\\ionic_2\\Ecommerce\\material\\node_modules\\ionic-angular',
npm ERR!   dest: 'F:\\ionic_2\\Ecommerce\\material\\node_modules\\.ionic-angular.DELETE',
npm ERR!   parent: 'material' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\sandip\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-12-18T05_20_48_850Z-debug.log
```

> Ionic info

cli packages: (C:\Users\sandip\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.3
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.1
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 6.5.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.1
Cordova Platforms  : android 7.1.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Node : v8.1.4
npm  : 6.5.0
OS   : Windows 8
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : E:\newsdk\newsdk\tools;E:\newsdk\newsdk\platform-tools;E:\newsdk\newsdk\build-tools
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

Comment: Try run as administrator

Comment: i had try but same issue.